# How can pass not only id but also full object into array list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, redux-form, admin-on-rest

**Dependencies:**

```
"admin-on-rest": "^1.3.3",
"base64-js": "^1.2.1",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0"
```

I have User model with List of Role.

```
// User
{
    id: "abcd1234",
    name: "John Doe",
    ...
    authorities: [
        {
            id: 12345,
            authority: "USER"
        },
        {
            id: 12346,
            authority: "ADMIN"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've used CheckboxArrayInput in order to display checkbox list.

```
<ReferenceArrayInput source="authorities" reference="roles" allowEmpty>
    <CheckboxGroupInput optionText="authority" optionValue="id" addField={true} />
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```

When item's checked It seems like just pass id to array list, not full of object as expected

[image]

I realized that in [Admin-on-Rest-demo](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/visitors/SegmentsInput.js), in this case with segments, it works fine. Though it can not apply to my project at all.

Answer (score 2):

Get object from id and use it :

```
// for example if 'id' represents your checkbox option value
const authority = user.authorities.filter(auth => auth.id === id);
```

Comment: Hi, @Fawaz. Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry for my lack of understanding, but I don't know how it can help me in this case. 
I just want to check "USER" box it will pass { id: 12345, authority: "USER" } into form. 

Cause my server handle full of model. Could you give me some more detail. I'm just newbie with Admin on rest. Thanks

Comment: @LongNguyen How are you handling form submit ? any specific library that you are using ? What I have stated above means that before submitting the form you would have to manipulate the data.

Comment: I'm using Admin-on-Rest library. This handles form submit (maybe redux-form). 
https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest

Comment: @LongNguyen Just checked the docs for this lib. It doesn't provides an onSubmit handler. You would have to fetch the correct object on server when user submits the data.

Comment: Thanks for your support.